# Microsoft Excel: Symbols are inconsistent sizes at same font size

Tags: microsoft-excel, fonts

[image: Example]

Excel seems to be warping the size of different symbols in its cells.

Here is the text in the image above copied directly from Excel, to illustrate:

"Press ⇧ + ⌥ + ⌃ + ⌘ + 8"

As seen here and in other word processors, symbols are normally a consistent size relative to each other and normal text.

I have tried various fonts and set the cell to a single font size, and the relative sizes of each symbol to each other remain the same. The cell format is "General" (and the problem remains with other formats such as "Text").

Any ideas how to fix this?

(I am running Excel 2017, Version 15.32, on macOS Sierra 10.12.3)

Answer (score 0):

Looks slightly better with *Arial Unicode MS*:

[image]

This is on a Win 7 machine.

Comment: Thanks; this doesn't quite solve the problem though. Even that font has a wonky Ctrl symbol, and it doesn't have a very gold Bold face. I'm more interested in why Excel is warping normal fonts' symbols.